# How can I retrieve all the roles (groups) a user is a member of?

Tags: .net, windows-identity, rbac, windows-principal

Is there a way to get a list of roles a Windows authenticated user is in, without explicitly checking by `WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole` method?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole` just checks if the user is a member of the group with that name; a Windows Group *is a* Role. You can get a list of the groups that a user is a member of from the `WindowsIdentity.Groups` property.

You can get `WindowsIdentity` from your `WindowsPrincipal`:

```
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsPrincipal.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
```

or you can get it from a factory method on WindowsIdentity:

```
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

`WindowsIdenity.Groups` is a collection of `IdentityReference` which just gives you the SID of the group.  If you need the group names you will need to translate the `IdentityReference` into an `NTAccount` and get the Value:

```
var groupNames = from id in identity.Groups
                 select id.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value;
```

Comment: I used `var identity = User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;`

Comment: this method doesn't show new groups I created, why ?

Comment: You have to logout and login back again.. this method only reads the security tokens. It does not query the DC again

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: Josh beat me to it! :)

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

            foreach (var groupId in identity.Groups)
            {
                var group = groupId.Translate(typeof (NTAccount));
                Console.WriteLine(group);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are not connected to the domain server, the `Translate` function may throw the following exception `The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.`

But for most of the groups, it will be OK, so I use:

```
foreach(var s in WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups) {
    try {
        IdentityReference grp = s.Translate(typeof (NTAccount)); 
        groups.Add(grp.Value);
    }
    catch(Exception) {  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In an ASP.NET MVC site, you can do it like this:

Add this to your Web.config:

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  ...
</system.web>
```

Then you can use `Roles.GetRolesForUser()` to get all the Windows groups that the user is a member of.  Make sure you're `using System.Web.Security`.